# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError from barcode4j-2.1.jar on jasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, barcode-printing, barcode4j

I'm trying to print barcode using Java (Web application)
and Using Jaspoersoft iReport Designer 4.5.0

Here is my Java code :

```
public String onBtnPrintClick() throws JRException, IOException {
    Integer pos_number = getMst_posService().getPosById((Integer) getSession().get("pos_id")).getPos_number();
    Date dateNow = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Integer total_paid = getPaidCard() + getPaidCash();

//      Bill printing   


    View_transactionprod_pos transactionProdToBill = new View_transactionprod_pos();
    transactionProdToBill.setTransaction_id(getTransactionIdFromMakeSale());

    listProdToBill = getView_transactionprod_posService().getViewTransactionProdPosListByModel(transactionProdToBill);

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    parameters.put("transaction_id", getTransactionIdFromMakeSale());
    parameters.put("pos_number", pos_number);
    parameters.put("transaction_date", dateFormatter.format(dateNow));
    parameters.put("total_price", getTotalPriceToSell());
    parameters.put("total_paid", total_paid);
    parameters.put("change", getChange());
    parameters.put("barcode", getTransactionIdFromMakeSale());

    return "pdf";
}
```

xml :

```
    <action name="MakeSalePrint" class="MakeSaleS" method="onBtnPrintClick">
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/makesale.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="json">/WEB-INF/jsp/makesale.jsp</result>
        <result name="pdf" type="jasper">
            <param name="location">/WEB-INF/report/Bill.jasper</param>
            <param name="dataSource">listProdToBill</param>
            <param name="format">PDF</param>
            <param name="documentName">reportDetail</param>
            <param name="reportParameters">parameters</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

When click print button It calls `onBtnPrintClick()` method.
I've imported some jars and added it to my project :

[image: Added to my project from myproject/src/main/webapp/lib]

in jrxml file barcode is *code128* and language is java

**Without the barcode it prints..**

I can't get that error class not found from barcode4j-2.1.jar

Error :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/krysalis/barcode4j/HumanReadablePlacement
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1992)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:733)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.readObject(JRBaseReport.java:729)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:110)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(JRLoader.java:86)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:323)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(JSONValidationInterceptor.java:116)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.interceptor.SecurityInterceptor.intercept(SecurityInterceptor.java:180)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
org.leco.filter.LecoDispatcher.doFilter(LecoDispatcher.java:26)
```

I can't solve that 
Help me..
Thank you.

EDITED..

Comment: also I'm using struts2 framework

Comment: Is that jar in your `WEB-INF/lib/` directory of your war?

Comment: no it's not in `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 8):

Try updating `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Version might be higher by the time you find this answer useful.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the class org/krysalis/barcode4j/HumanReadablePlacement is in your jar, and the container (tomcat or other) loads it in.

Comment: thanks for your answer, problem was the location of jar